# Get real date from the Postgresql even if the user change the local date of his PC

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

I have PostgreSQL installed on my PC (local) and protected with a password. I want to set my date inside it, and once it's done, even if the user changes the PC date (from Windows), I wnat to have all the time a possibility to get the real date from PostgreSQL.

So to make it simple, I want to have a possibility to get real date from the PostgreSQL even if the user change the local date of his PC.

PS: the PC is not connected to any network or internet.

Comment: Short answer: you can't Postgres always gets the date from the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your short answer, and do you have any idea how to get the real date without connecting to the internet, and even if the user change his PC date ?

Comment: Imagine you are in a room, you can't get access at the outside. In this room there is a clock, this clock shows you date/time. How can you get the real date/time ?

Comment: But why do you want to have a `real date` ? What do you want to to with this date? Calculate something, show the user a message `you have a wrong date` or so ?

Comment: I have a  software that allow to the user to creat a session,  each session contain lotof fields, in this session the user can do all the changes he want and do lotof acquisitions, but if the day is passed he can't anymore do any change or acquisition into this session. What i do, is i compare the curent day with the session day, if they are equal then the user can do all changes he want but if the the two dates are different then we don't allow the changements to the session. We can creat just one session per day.

Comment: The software works all the time like that, but now we want to make user pay per each session. For example if the user pay for one session for 25 Jul 2015, he can alwayse change his PC date to this date in the future to make others acquisitions.

Comment: @Joe Your design won't work without some kind of external input. If the user can change the clock, and you are relying on the clock, then that's it. For PostgreSQL to know the "real" time it'd need to have access to some separate hardware clock on the machine, and there's no such thing

Comment: is there any software to protect the date and time from change by user ?

Comment: Maybe this will help : By default on Win 7 machines, Local Service, Administrators and Users have rights to Change TimeZone.

If you would like to restrict then remove users from "Change the Time Zone" policy

Computer configuration => policies => windows settings => Security settings => local policies => user rights assignment => Change the Time Zone.